# Docker, Rails and a cron tasks: how to set up a Docker container to run cron Rails rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron

How can I set up properly a Docker instance to run `cronjob tasks` that execute Rails `rake tasks`?

I have been trying several things and I have all these problems:

- The `cron.d` file is not loaded
- There is not log if a cron task fails
- The environment in the cron task session is empty

Answer (score 0):

Because I have been dealing with all these problems for a while and I haven't find any solution in internet that solved all my problems I am pasting my solution here:

~/MyApp/crontab:

```
* * * * * root /bin/bash -l -c 'cd $RAILS_ROOT && bundle exec rake my_task' >> /var/log/app_cron.log 2>&1
```

~/MyApp/Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image:
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set our working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Setting env up
ENV RAILS_ENV="production"
ENV RACK_ENV="production"

# Adding gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test

# Adding project files
COPY . .

## Cron config

# Add crontab file to the cron.d directory
# Files in /etc/cron.d can not have names with "-" or ".". It can be problematic
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/app

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/app

# To load the env variables in cron sessions
# without this the user in the cron session won't be able to find commands and Gems
RUN printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment

# Run the command on container startup
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Comment: Hi,  
I heard about having cron (or other kind of process) running alongside your main application not being a good practice (don't really know why though).  
I have also a similar need and I'm planning to have a separate cron container.  
In that container the cron jobs will simply make requests to my rails app and this will trigger my tasks.  
I also thought about my cron task changing a file (in a shared docker volume) but I don't really know how to trigger the task upon a file change in the application side.  
Ruby should have file change detection, but I'm not sure if this is safer..

Answer (score 0):

For at simpler solution, you could use [Arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). It runs timed tasks within Rails itself. No need to use crontab.
It runs when rails is running. Just install gem and have your lines in config/initializers/arask.rb, for instance:

```
arask.create task: 'update:cache', cron: '*/5 * * * *' # Every 5 minutes
```